# How to upgrade Jfrog Artifactory pro to enterprise or enterprise+?

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli, jfrog-xray, jfrog-mission-control

In our organization, we are planning to purchase jfrog artifactory pro version on an initial level, but we have some questions we listed below.

Questions:

1. Are we able to upgrade from artifactory pro to enterprise or enterprise+ later on?
2. If Upgrade is possible from Pro to enterprise then is there any manual or document and where is it?

Answer (score 5):

All you need to do is pasting the Enterprise/Enterprise+ license in Artifactory Pro Web-UI License screen, or place it in the $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc/artifactory.lic file.
Enterprise/Enterprise plus are just licenses that enable extended features and functionalities to Artifactory Pro.